# How to automatically scale a table when it is combined with a ggplot using patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, datatable, patchwork

I'm using patchwork to assemble a plot and a table. The trouble is my table has quite a few columns, and so some disappear off the side. I want the table to scale so that whole thing becomes smaller to fit the space. Here's a simplified example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(ggpmisc)

# Make a wide dataframe for demo purposes
my_data <- mtcars
names(my_data) <- paste0(names(my_data), "_two")
my_data <- cbind(mtcars, my_data)

# 1. Create a scatter plot
my_plot <- ggplot(my_data, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "A Scatter Plot of mtcars")

# 2. Create a table plot
table_data <- head(my_data)
my_table_plot <- ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  annotate(geom = "table", x = 1, y = 1, label = list(table_data))

# 3. Combine plots with patchwork and adjust aspect ratio
my_assembled <- my_plot / my_table_plot + 
  plot_layout(heights = c(3, 1))

# Show the assembled plot
print(my_assembled)
```

[image]

As above, I know I can change the aspect ratio with `plot_layout(heights = c(3, 1))`, for example. However, this just changes the space available for the table. It doesn't actually make the table or its text smaller. Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you also using the `ggpp` library here for the table geom?

Comment: No, just `ggplot2` and `patchwork`

Comment: Or `ggpmisc`? The current v3.4.3 ggplot2 does not have a table geom. Does your code run in a fresh R session?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, the script above works on its own, with just `ggplot2` (3.4.2) and `patchwork`

Comment: I get `Error in 'annotate()': Can't find geom called "table"` if I have not loaded `ggpp`, but I get a result like yours if I have.

Comment: Looks like it must have been loaded elsewhere, perhaps a dependency, but it seems `ggpmisc` was loaded and required. I've updated above

Comment: Seems you need to say what sort of "scaling" would be acceptable. How many columns are there? What are the widths of the column headings?

Comment: The parameter `size` is accepted by `geom_table`. Have you tried reducing that parameter, say `... size=0.95, `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to use `flextable:gen_grob` to convert a flextable object to a grob that patchwork can use, and resize automatically to fit:

```
library(flextable)
my_plot + gen_grob(flextable(table_data)) +
  plot_layout(heights = c(3, 1))
```

[image]

Another option, as discussed in a `gt` issue, would be to render the table as an image and then combine that in: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/961

Comment: Flextable works brilliantly, thanks!